# NSTask to NSString compare don't work

Tags: shell, nsstring, nsdata, nstask

I'm currently trying to compare a shell output to a string.
But it won't work at all!

```
StringOne = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataTwo encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if([StringOne isEqualToString:@"get if addr en0 failed, (os/kern) failure"])
{
    NSLog(@"Failure!");
}
```

The dataTwo is returned by a NSData from NSPipe.
I tried almost everything and couldn't find anything on the internet on that.

Maybe you can help me.
Thanks!

**EDIT**
It just turned out, that the output string, I'm trying to compare, is with newline. *Hpf…*
I just added "\n" at the end to my compare-string and it worked!

Wo should all learn from that:
Check your stuff twice before posting on the net :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, that my shell output had a newline at the end.
I just added "\n" to my compare string:

`[StringOne isEqualToString:@"get if addr en0 failed, (os/kern) failure\n"]`

Now it works!